# Strong parameters and multidimensional arrays

Tags: ruby-on-rails, multidimensional-array, ruby-on-rails-3.2, strong-parameters

I'm using **Rails 3.2.6** with [strong parameters](https://github.com/rails/strong_parameters) gem.

So, I' have a controller with the typical update action:

```
# PUT /api/resources/:id
def update
  @resource.update_attributes! permited_params
  respond_with_json @resource, action: :show
end
```

Then, I have the `permited_params` method

```
def permited_params
  params.permit(:attr1, :attr2, :attr3)
end
```

The problem is that `:attr3` is a multidimensional array like this: `[[1, 2], [2, 5, 7]]`

Following the documentation, I need to specify `:attr3` as an array. But...

```
params.permit(:attr1, :attr2, :attr3 => [])
#inspecting permited_params: {"attr1"=>"blah", "attr2"=>"blah"}

params.permit(:attr1, :attr2, :attr3 => [[]])
#inspecting permited_params: {"attr1"=>"blah", "attr2"=>"blah", "attr3" => []}

params.permit(:attr1, :attr2, :attr3 => [][])
#throw error
```

The question is: **How can I use strong params with multidimensional arrays?**

Comment: are u serializing `attr3` while saving?

Comment: yes!,`:attr3` is defined on resource model as `serialize :attr3, JSON`. What are you thinking?

Comment: A multidimensional array is still one Array, containing arrays in each of its "indexes". So a simple `params.permit(:attr1, :attr2, :attr3 => [])` should be sufficient (following the doc)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can also do this in this way

```
   def permited_params
     hash = params.permit(:attr1, :attr2) 
     hash[:attr3] = params.require(:attr3) if params.has_key?(:attr3)
     hash
   end
```

Answer (score 3):

I was seeing this type of question many times so i though to dig into the code and find the reason and make it work.

It turns around that whatever written in documentation is correct. This is from strong parameter documentation.

> The permitted scalar types are String, Symbol, NilClass, Numeric, TrueClass, FalseClass, Date, Time, DateTime, StringIO, IO, ActionDispatch::Http::UploadedFile and Rack::Test::UploadedFile.

This `scalar` values are inside stored in `::ActionController::Parameters::PERMITTED_SCALAR_TYPE`

If you see its value, you will find that it doesn't accept `Array` as `value` .

To make this work, all you need to do to add `Array` into whitelist, i.e if you do

```
::ActionController::Parameters::PERMITTED_SCALAR_TYPE << Array
```

it will work. But this is bad solution. I'm not the strong_parameter contributor so i am not aware of security risks. So, to solve this problem all you have to do is to include  method in your controller something like this

```
def allow_array_in_strong_parameter
  old_scalar_types = ::ActionController::Parameters::PERMITTED_SCALAR_TYPES.dup
  ::ActionController::Parameters::PERMITTED_SCALAR_TYPES << Array
  params.permit(:attr1, :attr2, :attr3 => [])
  ::ActionController::Parameters::PERMITTED_SCALAR_TYPES = old_scalar_types
end
```

Comment: Definig permited_params as `params.permit(:attr1, :attr2, :attr3 => [])` and sending a simple array `"attr3"=>[1,2,3]` works perfectly. So, I insist, it must be a problem with multidimensional arrays or another issue.

Comment: if you send this `"attr3"=>[1,2,3]` the scalar values are `1`, `2` , `3` which is numeric so it is working. There is lot difference between  `"attr3"=>[1,2,3]` and `"attr3"=>[[1, 2], [2, 5, 7]]` . I am sorry, but you need to check `strong_paramter` gem to understand how does it work. The above answer is bare minimum.

Comment: posted second answer which might serve your needs in better way

Comment: Relax, I have misunderstood your answer. I tried with your first option and I have dynamic constant assignment error on this line: `::ActionController::Parameters::PERMITTED_SCALAR_TYPES = old_scalar_types`. I did "resolve" the problem using your second option before making the question here. Anyway, I will accept your second answer thinking that there is no a cleaner way based on the exposed on your first answer.