# ActiveModel::ForbiddenAttributesError in Rails 4?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I am getting the following error when trying to update a Rails model via the ActiveModel update method:

```
ActiveModel::ForbiddenAttributesError
```

I am aware of the strong parameters requirement in Rails 4 per the link below, but how do I whitelist the params in my case - an array of hashes?  I cannot make sense of the documentation.

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_controller_overview.html#strong-parameters

Here are the json params that I am trying to process:

```
{
    id: 1,
    month: 'April',
    measurements: [
        { id: 1, name: 'PT', location_1: '1.1', location_2: '1.2' },
        { id: 1, name: 'OT', location_1: '1.1', location_2: '1.2' },
        .
        .
    ]
}
```

Controller action:

```
  def update

    #Trying to update all measurements associated with this parent object

    #params.permit(measurements: [{ :name, :location_1, :location_2 } ])
    #This attempt causes a syntax error

    measurements = params[:measurements]

    measurements.each do |measurement|
      current_measurement = Measurement.find(measurement[:id])
      new_measurement = measurement.except(:id) 

      current_measurement.update(new_measurement)
    end
    .
    .

  end
```

Comment: try:   `params.permit(:month, measurements_attributes: [ :id, :name, :location_1, :location_2 ])`  (it may be singular instead of plural - can't remember so try that too)

Comment: refer http://stackoverflow.com/a/25211289/1377943

Comment: I'm getting the same error.  Any other ideas?  Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

to whitelist an array of attributes you'd code it this way...

```
params.permit(measurements: [ :name, :location_1, :location_2 ])
```

Comment: My array elements are hashes each containing these attributes.  Do you know how to code that?  I get the same error when trying the above.  Thanks!

Comment: Super late to the party, but for people stumbling upon this question, the answer is `params.permit(measurements: [[:name, :location_1, :location_2]])`.